# Dynamically created group is not reflecting in the check permissions in SharePoint 2013 on-prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, groups, check-permissions

I have created a few SharePoint groups through an `itemadded` event receiver in my on-premise solution. user will give a title for the group and click on save button and on `itemadded`, I am adding `sitegroup.add()` and calling the web.update();

When I added a user into the group and then I checked for this user in the check permissions in site settings, am not able to see the group name against this user.

Do I need to do any extra line of code in order to update / reflect the group name against the user in the check permissions ?

for the other groups and users which were created few weeks back working perfectly.

```
            var allgroups = CurrentWeb.SiteGroups;
             allgroups.Add(strDivGrpName, currUser, null, 
           strDivGrpName);
            CurrentWeb.AssociatedGroups.Add(CurrentWeb.SiteGroups
            [strDivGrpName]);
                         allgroups.Add(strDivGrpName, currUser, null, 
               strDivGrpName);
               CurrentWeb.AssociatedGroups.Add(CurrentWeb.SiteGroups
          [strDivGrpName]);
                         CurrentWeb.Update();
```

[image: UNABLE2SEEgroupname]